# Cambiar estilo css en un navegador en concreto

Tags: html, css, firefox

¿Hay alguna manera para poder cambiar un estilo solo en un navegador en concreto?

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esta pregunta de SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547370/is-there-a-way-to-set-any-style-for-a-specific-browser-in-css?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Hola davescode, deberías añadir algo más de información a la pregunta: ¿Es un estilo específico o quieres que toda la página se vea diferente? ¿Puedes usar JavaScript o lenguajes del lado del servidor? Lee [ask] para más información y consejos. Generalmente tener estilos dependientes del navegador no es algo ideal, ¿qué es lo que estás intentando hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Podes generar una clase padre para que muestre un estilo u otro dependiendo del navegador y con una función en javascript obtengo el navegador para agregarlo como `class`. Por ejemplo:

```js
function getBrowser() {
  // Opera 8.0+
  if ((!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0) {
    return 'opera';
  }
  
  // Firefox 1.0+
  if (typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined') {
    return 'firefox';
  }

  // Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
  if (/constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && safari.pushNotification))) {
    return 'safari';
  }

  // Internet Explorer 6-11
  if (/*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode) {
    return 'ie';
  }

  // Edge 20+
  if (!!window.StyleMedia) {
    return 'edge';
  }

  // Chrome 1+
  if (!!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore) {
    return 'chrome';
  }

  // Blink engine detection
  if ((isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS) {
    return 'blink';
  }
}

// agrego la clase al #container
document.getElementById('container').classList.add(getBrowser());
```

```css
.nombre {
  color: white;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

.chrome .nombre {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
}

.firefox .nombre {
  color: blue;
  background: red;
}

.ie .nombre {
  color: yellow;
  background: green;
}

.edge .nombre {
  color: white;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="nombre">
    Stackoverflow
  </div>
</div>
```